# Remove Pseudo Class (hover) Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove the box shadow effect from the hover when the button is clicked only using Javascript not jQquery.The add rule property is working well but not the removerule property.

JavaScript

```
  function anim()
    {

        document.styleSheets[0].removeRule('#fab:hover { box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23); }', 0);
        var div = document.getElementById('fab');
        div.className="anim";





    }
```

HTML

```
<button  onclick="anim()" id="fab">+</button>
```

CSS

```
#fab
{
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 45px;
    outline: 0;
    border:0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;

    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#fab:hover
{
     box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the `:active` and `:focus` states? pure CSS.

```
#fab:active, #fab:focus {
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
#fab {
  margin-right: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 45px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#fab:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

#fab:active, #fab:focus {
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

```html
<button id="fab">+</button>
```

Comment: Yeah it's working on a button but i cant do that on a div for example

Comment: @zaarr78 Ok, that was not explained in the question. However, by default, `:focus` does not work for divs.. UNLESS you add the `tabindex` attribute. See my working [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/181Lky0n/3/).

Answer (score 1):

While I could provide you a solution *as is*, it seems like your issue is easier to solve using CSS classes:

#### HTML

```
<button  onclick="anim()" class="fab some-class-name">+</button>
```

#### JS

```
function anim()
{
  document.querySelector(".fab").classList.remove("some-class-name");
}
```

#### CSS

```
.fab
{
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 45px;
    outline: 0;
    border:0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;

    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.some-class-name:hover
{
     box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);

}
```

Comment: I thought this could work but for some reasons it seems that some-class-name:hover does nothing

Comment: @zaarr78 Read my answer carefully. You need to remove the `some-class-name` only and since CSS defines a `:hover` for that class, removing the whole class, also removes `:hover`

Comment: @zaarr78 I had to add `!important` to your codepen on `box-shadow` to let it work..

Comment: @zaarr78 I've re-updated my answer. In your case I would turn `fab` into a CSS class too, I suspect that you're going to use the whole style in more *fab* buttons... Now you don't need `!important` anymore